# php string 't' change to '=';

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, email

I have a strange problem.

```
$body = 'Hi there, <br /><br /> 
        A new label request has been made on Our Trading Platform.';

    $this->CI->email->from($from, 'Our Trading Platform');
    $this->CI->email->to($to);
    $this->CI->email->cc($cc);

    $this->CI->email->subject($subject);
    $this->CI->email->message($body);   

    if($this->CI->email->send())
        return TRUE;
    else
        echo $this->CI->email->print_debugger();
```

Above is my php email body. In the email it become:

'Hi there, 
 
            A new label request has been made on Our Trading Pla=form.';

What I do with my $body is sending email using the email library of codeigniter.
The 't' change to '='. What is wrong with my string?

Comment: What does `var_dump( $body );` output?

Comment: Are you looking the email source? Or you are receiving it like this in your mail client?

Comment: @DamienPirsy Yes I did, the source code is '='

Comment: You've discovered the infamous t-change bug (it used to be a c-change bug).... either that or you've forgotten something, like to post your code showing what you do with this $body string

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your string. There's probably something wrong with the rest of your code

Comment: @AmalMurali The var_dump gave me the 't'

Comment: So, if PHP was changing the `t`'s in the string `=` (which it's not, you are somewhere), then why is the `t` in `request` preserved?

Comment: @etlds: We need more code.

Comment: If it's in an email, it's probably to do with the encoding (badly encoded emails can end up with `=` on the end of each line, for example). But really not possible to give much more help without seeing a lot more code.

Comment: Are you chunk_splitting to build your email body?

Comment: OK！Thank you for the tips guys! After adding 'charset' => 'utf-8' to my $config of email. The problem fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a encoding problem. Make sure your source file is using the same encoding as the message you are sending. Try setting everything to UTF-8.